# wait() hangs when CLONE_THREAD

Tags: c++, c, linux, ptrace, seccomp

I am tracing some processes and their children using ptrace. I am trying to print specific system call (using Seccomp filter that notifies ptrace, see [this blogpost](https://www.alfonsobeato.net/c/filter-and-modify-system-calls-with-seccomp-and-ptrace/)).

In most cases my code (see below) is working fine. However, when I am tracing a java program (from the default-jre package), the latter clones using the `CLONE_THREAD` flag. And for some reason, my tracer hangs (I believe) because I can't receive signals from the cloned process. I think the reason is that (according to [this discussion](https://www.spinics.net/lists/newbies/msg23170.html)) the child process in fact becomes a child of the original process' parent, instead of becoming the original process' child.

I reproduced this issue by using a simple program that simply calls `clone()` with flags and perform actions. When I used the when I use `CLONE_THREAD | CLONE_SIGHAND | CLONE_VM` flags (as [clone() documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) specifies they should come together since Linux 2.6.0), at least I am able to trace everything correctly until one of the two thread finishes.

I would like to trace both thread independently. Is it possible?

More importantly, I need to trace a Java program, and I cannot change it. Here a strace of the Java program clone call:

```
[...]
4665  clone(child_stack=0x7fb166e95fb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tid=[4666], tls=0x7fb166e96700, child_tidptr=0x7fb166e969d0) = 4666
[...]
```

So Java seems to respect the rules. I wanted to experiment to understand: I ruled out any flags unrelated to thread (i.e., `CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_SYSVSEM).

Here are the results of running my test program with different combination of flags (I know, I am really desperate):

- `CLONE_VM|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SETTLS`: only gets trace from parent
- `CLONE_VM|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID`: inconsistent; gets trace from both until the parent finishes
- `CLONE_VM|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID`: inconsistent; gets trace from both until the child finishes
- `CLONE_VM|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID`: only gets trace from parent
- `CLONE_VM|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID`: only gets trace from parent
- `CLONE_VM|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_SETTLS`: only gets trace from parent
- `CLONE_VM|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID`: inconsistent; gets trace from both until the child finishes
- `CLONE_VM|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_SETTLS`: only gets trace from parent
- `CLONE_VM|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID`: inconsistent; gets trace from both until the child finishes
- `CLONE_VM|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID`:
  only gets trace from parent

So at least I get the same behaviour from my program and the Java program: it does not work.

How can I make it work? For instance, how does `strace` successfully traces any kind of clone? I tried to dig into its code but I can't find how they are doing it.

Any help might appreciated!
Best regards,

The tracer code (compile with `g++ tracer.cpp -o tracer -g -lseccomp -lexplain`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/reg.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/limits.h>
#include <linux/filter.h>
#include <linux/seccomp.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <libexplain/waitpid.h>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>


#define DEFAULT_SIZE 1000
#define MAX_SIZE 1000

int process_signals();
int inspect(pid_t);
void read_string_into_buff(const pid_t, unsigned long long, char *, unsigned int);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  pid_t pid;
  int status;

  if (argc < 2) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <prog> <arg1> ... <argN>\n", argv[0]);
      return 1;
  }

  if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
      /* If execve syscall, trace */
      struct sock_filter filter[] = {
          BPF_STMT(BPF_LD+BPF_W+BPF_ABS, offsetof(struct seccomp_data, nr)),
          BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP+BPF_JEQ+BPF_K, __NR_getpid, 0, 1),
          BPF_STMT(BPF_RET+BPF_K, SECCOMP_RET_TRACE),
          BPF_STMT(BPF_RET+BPF_K, SECCOMP_RET_ALLOW),
      };
      struct sock_fprog prog = {
          .len = (unsigned short) (sizeof(filter)/sizeof(filter[0])),
          .filter = filter,
      };
      ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0);
      if (prctl(PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS, 1, 0, 0, 0) == -1) {
            perror("prctl(PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS)");
            return 1;
      }
      if (prctl(PR_SET_SECCOMP, SECCOMP_MODE_FILTER, &prog) == -1) {
          perror("when setting seccomp filter");
          return 1;
      }
      kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP);
      return execvp(argv[1], argv + 1);
  } else {
      waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
      ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, pid, 0, PTRACE_O_TRACESECCOMP | PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK | PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE | PTRACE_O_TRACEVFORK );
      ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, 0, 0);
      process_signals();
      return 0;
  }
}


int process_signals(){
  int status;
  while (1){
    pid_t child_pid;
    // When child status changes
    if ((child_pid = waitpid(-1, &status, 0)) < 0){
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", explain_waitpid(child_pid, &status, 0));
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //printf("Sigtrap received\n");
    // Checking if it is thanks to seccomp
    if (status >> 8 == (SIGTRAP | (PTRACE_EVENT_SECCOMP << 8))){
      // Perform argument inspection with ptrace
      int syscall = inspect(child_pid);
    }
    // Resume no matter what
    ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child_pid, 0, 0);
  }
}

int inspect(pid_t pid){
  printf("From PID: %d\n", pid);
  struct user_regs_struct regs;
  ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, &regs);
  // Get syscall number
  int syscall = regs.orig_rax;
  printf("------\nCaught syscall: %d\n", syscall);

  if (syscall == __NR_getpid){
    printf("Getpid detected\n");
  }
  return syscall;
}

void read_string_into_buff(const pid_t pid, unsigned long long addr, char * buff, unsigned int max_len){
  /* Are we aligned on the "start" front? */
  unsigned int offset=((unsigned long)addr)%sizeof(long);
  addr-=offset;
  unsigned int i=0;
  int done=0;
  int word_offset=0;

  while( !done ) {
    unsigned long word=ptrace( PTRACE_PEEKDATA, pid, addr+(word_offset++)*sizeof(long), 0 );
    // While loop to stop at the first '\0' char indicating end of string
    while( !done && offset<sizeof(long) && i<max_len ) {
      buff[i]=((char *)&word)[offset]; /* Endianity neutral copy */

      done=buff[i]=='\0';
      ++i;
      ++offset;
    }

    offset=0;
    done=done || i>=max_len;
  }
}
```

The sample program (compile with `gcc sample.c -o sample`):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define FLAGS CLONE_VM|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID

int fn(void *arg)
{
   printf("\nINFO: This code is running under child process.\n");

   int i = 0;
   int n = atoi(arg);
   for ( i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; i++ )
      printf("[%d] %d * %d = %d\n", getpid(), n, i, (n*i));

   printf("\n");

   return 0;
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   printf("[%d] Hello, World!\n", getpid());

   void *pchild_stack = malloc(1024 * 1024);
   if ( pchild_stack == NULL ) {
      printf("ERROR: Unable to allocate memory.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   int pid = clone(fn, pchild_stack + (1024 * 1024), FLAGS, argv[1]);
   if ( pid < 0 ) {
        printf("ERROR: Unable to create the child process.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   fn(argv[1]);

   wait(NULL);

   free(pchild_stack);

   printf("INFO: Child process terminated.\n");
}
```

You can test what you want by running `./tracer ./sample`. You can also test the original test case `./tracer java` and observe that both the tracer and java hangs.

**ANSWER:**
As pointed it out in the comment, I had issues in that example that were preventing me from handling signals from the child.

In my original code (not listed here because too complex), I was only attaching ptrace AFTER the processes started... and I was only attaching to PID listed by pstree. My mistake was that I omitted the threads (and java is one program that does create threads), explaining why I had issue tracing java only.
I modified the code to attach to all the children process and thread (`ps -L -g <Main_PID> -o tid=`) and everything works again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample program has a bug: it may free the second thread’s stack before that thread exits, causing a SEGV. And your tracer just doesn’t handle signals well.

If the traced program gets a signal, your tracer intercepts it, not passing it down to the program. When it continues the program, it continues from the very same operation that caused SEGV, so it gets SEGV again. Ad infinitum. Both the tracer and the tracee appear to hang but in fact, they are in an infinite loop.

Rewriting the continuation like the following seems to work:

```c
        if (status >> 8 == (SIGTRAP | (PTRACE_EVENT_SECCOMP << 8))){
            // Perform argument inspection with ptrace
            int syscall = inspect(child_pid);
            ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child_pid, 0, 0);
        } else if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
            ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child_pid, 0, WSTOPSIG(status));
        } else {
            ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child_pid, 0, 0);
        }
```

Not sure of Java but it seems to get SEGVs in regular operation...

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot for your answer. It solves one part of my issue: I did not realize I had to handle the signals and give them to the child. Indeed, java seems to have sigsegv and this is apparently normal. Is there a generic way to handle all the signals or should I handle them myself?

I still have the main issue which is that, after I do a clone with CLONE_THREAD, child and parent have the same PID (but there TIDs are different). It causes me issues because I think ptrace cannot attach to that new clone. I will investigate and update.
Thanks again

Comment: Hi again. I solved the second issue. My problem was that, in the original program, I only attached ptrace AFTER the java process started ... and I only attached ptrace to children PIDs listed, completely omitted the threads (I was not aware of the difference). I modified my code and attached ptrace to the thread (listing /proc/<pid>/task/) and everything runs fine. Thanks a lot again!